# Why selecting columns with an element of a character vector requires get() in data.table?

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, subset

#### Context

I store variable names of interest in a character vector. Usually, I store those vectors in a nested list (e.g. `variables$predictors$model1`), as to reduce clutter and better organize them. For this reason, I usually work with sublists and indexing of lists. However, I am having a hard time translating this workflow into `data.table`.

#### Problem

Consider the simple task of subsetting the data.table to a subset of columns whose names are in a character vector. As you can see, the commonly suggested manners to subset do not give the intended output. What is more annoying, the desired output requires using `get()` (together with a list) which has occasionally undesired behavior.

**Is this really the most efficient way available within `data.table` for this simple action?**

Why do options 1 to 4 return just the string?

```
library(data.table)

# Create data.table with three variables
dt                       <- data.table(a = c(1:3, NA), b = 1:4, c = c(NA, 1:3))

# Define column names of interest
column_names_of_interest <- c("b", "c")

# Subset by one of the column names
# Attempted approaches

# 1
dt[, column_names_of_interest[1]]
#[1] "b"

# 2
dt[, column_names_of_interest[[1]]]
# [1] "b"

# 3
dt[, ..column_names_of_interest[1]]
# [1] "b"

# 4
dt[, ..column_names_of_interest[[1]]]
# [1] "b"

# 5
dt[, get(column_names_of_interest[1])]
# [1] 1 2 3 4

# 6
dt[, .(get(column_names_of_interest[1]))]
#     V1
# 1:  1
# 2:  2
# 3:  3
# 4:  4
```

Comment: Check new env argument in devel version of data.table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1:3, NA), b = 1:4, c = c(NA, 1:3))

column_names_of_interest <- c("b", "c")

dt[, .SD, .SDcols = column_names_of_interest]

#    b  c
# 1: 1 NA
# 2: 2  1
# 3: 3  2
# 4: 4  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The approach begs the follow-up question of what would be the most concise way to operate over the .SDcols then, since we cannot directly make reference to `.SDcols`, no? For instance, if we want to replace the 3's with NA's in the columns of interest, is `dt[, (column_names_of_interest) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == 3, NA, x)), .SDcols = column_names_of_interest]` the most straightforward way to do so?

Comment: @Kuku, yes if you do not want to subset your data.table, but want to do an operation only on the columns defined in .SDcols your code is exactly the way to go and those columns are efficiently updated by reference. If you also want to subset the data.table (and return only column b and c) itself and do the operation it would be `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == 3, NA, x)), .SDcols = column_names_of_interest]`